# Get Only first object from Mongo Cursor

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm making a query to a MongoDB and I only want the first object. I know I could use `findOne`, but I'm still confused where I'm going wrong.

This does not work:

```
if ($cursor->count() > 0) {
    $image = $cursor->current();
    // neither does this work
    // $image = $cursor[0]; 
    return $image;
} else {
    return false;
}   

//echo $image->filename;
// Throws error: Trying to access property of non-object image
```

This works though:

```
if ($cursor->count() > 0) {
    $image = null;
    foreach($cursor as $obj)
        $image = $obj;
    return $image;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How about this:

```
if ($cursor->count() > 0) {
    $cursor->next();
    $image = $cursor->current();
    return $image;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Bonus: quote from [the Doc page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.current.php)

> **public array MongoCursor::current (void)**
> This returns NULL until
>   MongoCursor::next() is called.

Comment: Yes, that works. Wow...that was silly on my part. Will accept as soon as I can.

Comment: It's ok, I was surprised by this too not so long time ago. )

Answer (score 0):

Solution provided by raina77ow uses [Mongo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php) library which is marked as legacy.

At the moment there is only one way to get first element from cursor - use [MongoDB\Driver\Cursor::toArray](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-cursor.toarray.php) method:

```
$cursor = $collection->find();
$firstDocument = $cursor->toArray()[0];
```

Comment: Call to undefined method MongoCursor::toArray()